# Add Row Values as Columns to Existing Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

It seems like the answer for me lies somewhere within PIVOT and dynamic SQL but I can't put the pieces together. I have the following table.

```
FieldId InternalFieldName  FieldLabel
1       RepairableSpare_1  CField0
6       Equipment_6        CField1
7       Equipment_7        CField2
8       Equipment_8        CField3
9       Equipment_9        CField4
```

I need to add the values in the FieldLabel column, as their own columns in another table.

End goal would be:

```
OtherTableID OtherTableColumnA CField0 CField1 CField2 CField3 CField4
ID1          ColumnValue       VALUE   VALUE   VALUE   VALUE   VALUE
```

I have a third table that I can use to populate the VALUES in those CField columns, I just can't figure out how to get them as columns in the OtherTable.

### EDIT

I've attached an image of the tables I'm working with and text information below.
[image]

CustomField Table

```
FieldId InternalFieldName FieldLabel
6       Equipment_6       CustomField1
7       Equipment_7       CustomField2
8       Equipment_8       CustomField3
9       Equipment_9       CustomField4
```

Equipment Table

```
EquipmentId EquipmentNo
7362        ..12
8696        ..12_COPY2
```

Desired Table

```
EquipmentId EquipmentNo CustomField1 CustomField2 CustomField3 CustomField4
7362        ..12
8696        ..12_COPY2
```

Important note, the number of custom fields is not static.

### EDIT2

I thought I could figure it out from a certain point, but it looks like that was not the (big shout out to D-shih for sticking with me) case. Below I've included the other table I'll need to work with that I thought I could figure out myself.

I have 3 tables:

CustomField Table

```
FieldId InternalFieldName FieldLabel
6       Equipment_6       CustomField1
7       Equipment_7       CustomField2
8       Equipment_8       CustomField3
9       Equipment_9       CustomField4
```

CustomFieldRelationshipTable

```
FieldValueId FieldId EquipmentId FieldValue
66           6       7431        True
67           7       7431        1900-01-01
68           8       7431        1900-01-01
69           9       7431        NULL
```

Equipment Table

```
EquipmentId EquipmentNo
7431         ..12
```

Desired Table

```
EquipmentId EquipmentNo CustomField1 CustomField2 CustomField3 CustomField4
7431        ..12        True         1900-01-01   1900-01-01   NULL
```

Comment: What's the relationship between sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih There is no direct relationship between the sample data and expected result. 

The essential structure is:

Table A 
Table B
Table C

I need rows from Table A, to be added as Columns on Table C, these columns will be filled in with data from Table B.

Table B has a relationship to Table A and C.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to use `CROSS APPLY` with condition aggregate function.

and execute by dynamic SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE CustomField(
  FieldId INT,
  InternalFieldName VARCHAR(50),
  FieldLabel VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO  CustomField VALUES (6,'Equipment_6','CustomField1');
INSERT INTO  CustomField VALUES (7,'Equipment_7','CustomField2');
INSERT INTO  CustomField VALUES (8,'Equipment_8','CustomField3');
INSERT INTO  CustomField VALUES (9,'Equipment_9','CustomField4');

CREATE TABLE Equipment(
  EquipmentId INT,
  EquipmentNo VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO Equipment VALUES (7362,'..12');
INSERT INTO Equipment VALUES (8696,'..12_COPY2');

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',max(case when FieldLabel = ''' + FieldLabel + ''' then InternalFieldName end) ' +    QUOTENAME(FieldLabel) 
            FROM CustomField
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');


set @query = 'SELECT EquipmentId,EquipmentNo,'+@cols+'
FROM 
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM CustomField
) ta CROSS APPLY 
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM Equipment
) tb
GROUP BY  EquipmentId,
       EquipmentNo
'


EXECUTE(@query)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1ee672958d4654d2d98bc6a414c6153f)

---

if you want to let `CustomField` be the empty string you just modify the `case when`

```
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',max(case when FieldLabel = '''' then InternalFieldName end) ' +    QUOTENAME(FieldLabel) 
            FROM CustomField
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=40aa6f1b39fd3afe9a6b6dc32ad457e0)

Comment: Appreciate the response, but not quite.
Cross apply will add each column in Table B for each row in table B.

I need to take the values from the FieldLabel column (see original post for table structure), and add those as columns on the  other table.

So part of this process, is logically (if not syntactically) a pivot of one table, then taking that result and adding it to another table.

Comment: @MPJ567 Ok Could you provide some sample data and expect the result for your question? that can let the question more clearly.

Comment: please see edit,  and thanks for your continued assistance.

Comment: That was perfect, although unfortunately it turns out I couldn't actually figure out how to go from what you provided me, to my final answer. I've edited again, including information from the the relationship table I intended to pull data from. If you've got any patience left to help me out, I'd appreciate it.